# extra parameters added to my website after Conversion api gateway setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api

new to FB pixels and aws
the idea to create conversion api gateway using aws from FB event manager created the stack, added the A record in DNS finished the rest of the setup in event manager.
i had 2 issue the first one i couldn't log to the screen where i can log into console and see the event triggered.
the second issue which most important to me is we have an extra parameter appended to our main website url if we want to go to home page we type [www.xxxxx.com](http://www.xxxxx.com), when the page load the url is :
[www.xxxxx.com/?_atid=9A7BYbPsbuWoKng5bQMvhCfscXiWPS](http://www.xxxxx.com/?_atid=9A7BYbPsbuWoKng5bQMvhCfscXiWPS)
my question why this extra url added and how to get rid off?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i found out that it is a 3rd party tracking app i have installed which it inject the a script in the header of my main website so it tracks event activity, I installed to keep track events but didn't know or they don't mention in their docs it will change the url to something completely random which it could through savvy internet user away from your website.
thanks